# System.DirectoryServices - how to NOT query Active Directory for properties having the confidential bit set

Tags: .net, active-directory, directoryservices

I'm using DirectoryServices to query for DirectoryEntries for a person or group like so:

```
var propsToLoad = new string {"sAMAccountName","objectClass", "memberOf", "distinguishedName", "manager","mail","name","objectCategory"};
DirectoryEntry dEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<MyDomainController>/DC=foo,FC=com","user","pass");
DirectorySearcher dSearch = new DirectorySearcher(dEntry, "(&(|(objectClass=person)(objectClass=group))
(samAccountName=jsmith))", propsToLoad);
var searchResult = s.FindOne();
var searchResultDirEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
```

The issue I'm having is that the above call for getting the `DirectoryEntry` for the `SearchResult` is fetching more properties than what I'm querying for.
If I hover over the `searchResult` while debugging, it contains just the 8 properties I queried for but calling `"GetDirectoryEntry()"` on the `searchResult` queries for a ton more 
properties(approx 77 - 80 more property values).

The real problem is that it is also querying for properties whose "**confidential bit**" is set such as *'UnixUserPassword'*
causing audit failures on the DC.

Is there any way to specify NOT to query for any properties having the confidential bit set OR have the `result.GetDirectoryEntry();` respect 
my "propsToLoad" and only fetch property values for properties that I've specified on the `DirectorySearcher`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not really. Your propsToLoad array is passed in to the LDAP search. When you call the GetDirectoryEntry() API, it's a totally different codepath. If you want this level of control you're going to need to go against LDAP directly with S.DS.Protocols.

Comment: Are there any examples of doing this within the "System.DirectortyServices" namespace?

Comment: As I said, ADSI doesn't let you control this based on how its schema reflection works.

Comment: I ended up just querying the SearchResult for the PropertyValues instead of going down to using S.DS